# How to handle a large numbers of arrays with multiple loops in Javascript or Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops, foreach

I am trying to generate words for a dictionary like this.

HTML

```
 <div class="print"></div>
```

Javascript

```
    var c = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]
    var v = ["a","e","i","o","u"]

    var gen = '';
    for (i = 0; i = c.length; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < v.length; j++) {
            gen += c[i] + v[j] + '<br>';
        }
    }
    $('.print').html(gen);
```

But my browser can't handle the loop.

And It display a message like this.

> Aw, Snap! Something went wrong while displaying this webpage.

---

The above arrays are just an example, the actual arrays look like this.

```
 var c = ["ၵ", "ၶ", "င", "ၸ", "သ", "ၺ", "တ", "ထ", "ၼ", "ပ", "ၽ", "ၾ", "မ", "ယ", "ရ", "လ", "ဝ", "ႁ", "ဢ"];
```

Some arrays has more than 40 characters.

Although I reduced the loops into two times, it doesn't work.

1 - How to handle large numbers of arrays with multiple loops in Javascript or Jquery?

2 - If there is a good software or program that can generate a large numbers of words, Please recommend me.

Comment: `i = c.length;` should probably be `i < c.length;`. typo question

Comment: Thanks @CertainPerformance  , It's my mistake that I use a different font in my text editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a type in your code. the correct JavaScript snippet is like this:

```
var c = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]
var v = ["a","e","i","o","u"]

var gen = '';
for (i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < v.length; j++) {
        gen += c[i] + v[j] + '<br>';
    }
}
$('.print').html(gen);
```

Just check the parent loop it should be like : `i < c.length;`

Comment: Typo questions are *off-topic*. Answering is not appropriate - post a comment and vote to close (or flag) instead.